# how do I make it update two tables instead of only `accounts`?

Tags: php, sql

I am making it to where it sends to two tables instead of just the `accounts` I want it to go in `accounts` AND `groups`

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){


if (!(isset($_SESSION['sess_user']) || $_SESSION['sess_user'] == '')) {
header("location:index.php");
}

$dbcon = mysqli_connect('host.com', 'db', 'pass', 'db') or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));

$newname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['newname']);
$newname2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['newname2']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_SESSION['sess_user']);

if ($newname <> $newname2) { echo "Your fraternity names do not match.";}
```

**how would i make it updates two tables instead of just accounts?**

```
else if ((mysqli_query($dbcon, "UPDATE `accounts` 
                  SET `groupname`='".$newname."', 
                      `founder` ='".$username."' 
                  WHERE `username` = '".$username."'")))

{ 

echo "Your fraternity has been created. You will now be logged out.";

echo "<META http-equiv='refresh' content='3;URL=logout.php'>";

}

else { mysqli_error($dbcon); }

mysqli_close($dbcon);
}
?>
```

Comment: oh no, it didnt work, but let me explain in more detail, as you see, accounts says "   WHERE username =  " well, table " groups " doesnt have username, it only has groupname and founder, what do i do?

Comment: For update two table you can use two seperete update query for it

Comment: i know, i get that, BUT    ACCOUNTS HAS THE ROW " USERNAME ", GROUP DOES NOT

Comment: get what im saying? haha

Comment: then update groups table using where foundername=""

Comment: i know, but i want it as username so that the founder of the group which would be the account username, has certain permission, therefor i cant do that :(

Comment: and if they submit, it wont have a foundername -_- it cant be submitted by foundername because foundername wont exist yet -_- until they submit this form...

Comment: _can i put two_

else if ((mysqli_query($dbcon, "UPDATE `accounts` UPDATE `groups`
                      SET `groupname`='".$newname."', 
                          `founder` ='".$username."' 
                      WHERE `username` = '".$username."'")))

else if ((mysqli_query($dbcon, "UPDATE `groups`
                      SET `groupname`='".$newname."', 
                          `founder` ='".$username."'))) 

*like that?*

Comment: Then you have to insert data into the group table....because group table has no common fields..So first update accounts table and insert the data into grouptablle

Comment: okay let me see if that will work

Comment: thats not possible @viewers.gq username is not in the groups table so you cant use this  UPDATE groups SET groupname='".$newname."', founder ='".$username."' WHERE username = '".$username.

Comment: ...... i know. therefor how can i do this

Comment: insert the data into a group table

Comment: thats what ive been asking -_- omg , how would i do that.....

Comment: ok what are the fields in accounts and group table???...I will tell you the query

Comment: .......thats unimportant

Comment: forget that, tell me how i can do this

if(empty($rows['groupname']))
{

   echo  "You arent in any fraternity. Would you like to <a href='begin'>join one</a>?";

}
else 
{
if $f = $username

    // Do stuff with the field
    echo "You are in the $g fraternity, Founded by You! ";

}
if $f doesnt = $username
{

    echo "You are in the $g fraternity, Founded by $f ";

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$group = mysqli_query($dbconn,"select * from group where founder =".$username);
foreach($group as $row)
if(empty($row['founder']))
{
   echo "You arent in any fraternity. Would you like to <a href='begin'>join one</a>?";  
}else{
   echo "You are in.."
}
```